# Jquery Ajax API Error: 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, cloudsight

I am trying to make an Ajax POST request to an image recognition API called Cloudsight using Jquery. So far my code is:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests",
  Authorization: "CloudSight [key]",
  data: {
    remote_image_url: "https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
    locale: "en-US"
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I try to run it I get the Error: 400 (Bad Request) What am I doing wrong? As far as I can see the code seems to be alright...

Comment: I got: `{error: "Non OAuth request received"}`

Comment: Have you verified with the cloudsight API documentation that you are providing all the necessary fields? I can't seem to access it so I can't be sure on my own.

Comment: There could be an issue with the URL.

Comment: According to their documention: https://cloudsight.readme.io/ you must supply an image and a locale which I have done. The URL is just the google logo from the new tab page; I was using it as a test. They have a demo on their website which I just tested, and it doesn't seem to be working so their service may be down. However, I don't think I'd be getting this error if it was so I think something is wrong with the code? I took Bad Request to mean I had formed the request wrong.

Comment: `Authorization` isn't an option to `$.ajax`.  jQuery just ignores that option.

Comment: P.S. That's not your *real* API key, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else looks at this, managed to solve the problem with this code:

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "CloudSight [key]");
  },
  data: {
    "image_request[remote_image_url]": "https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
    "image_request[locale]": "en-US"
  },
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log("It worked! :D Good POST request.");
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(msg.token);
    console.log(msg.url);
    console.log(msg.responseText);

    token = msg.token;
  },
  error: function(msg) {
    console.log("Sorry...");
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(msg.responseText);
  }
});
```

Thanks to Mario Cezar for his help with the authorization!

Comment: You should accept your answer, not mine. Though mine helped you, it didn't provided you with the full answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
beforeSend: function (req){
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "CloudSight [key]");
},
```

Comment: When I do that with the colon, it gives me a syntax error, but if I add a comma instead (is that the correct syntax?) it gives me the same error as before...

Comment: It is indeed a comma. I'll fix it.

Comment: Good to know, but I'm still getting the 400 Bad Request error. Any other ideas? :/